# Should I include 2006 Time Magazine Person of the Year on resume?

Tags: resume, job-search

I am the [Time Person of the Year for 2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_(Time_Person_of_the_Year)), and I was wondering if this is a good idea to include this on my resume? I figured it might make me stand out and be more noticeable amid all the many other resumes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s just a joke

Comment: Between the sparkles coming from my mouse pointer and this sort of post I dont even know where I am.  I'm going home.  Argue amongst yourselves.

Comment: Actually an honest question. Would adding a subtle joke like this make me more noticeable?

Comment: Unless you're interviewing for a job as a comedian, leave your attempts at cheeky humor out of your resume.

Comment: @theresawalrus it will definitely make you more noticeable

Comment: But say I'm applying for a high demand job, where there are many applications/job. Would just being noticed be worth the chance they don't like the non-professionalism?

Comment: Nope. No it wouldn't.

Comment: @bruglesco Could you explain why the trade-off wouldn't be worth it, maybe as an answer?

Comment: Funnily enough, I'm the winner of the 2012 Nobel Peace Prize. I'm a modest person though, so I don't include it in my resume.

Comment: I actually think this is a valid question to ask since while it may be intended as a joke it IS a VALID credential. Just because every other person alive shares that credential doesn't make it any less real. As an alternate example: Imagine first responders for 9/11 were chosen as 'persons of the year' It decreases the size of people awarded this honor but does it make any real difference?

Comment: Well, I think you've come to a low after your Time Magazine Person of the Year achievement....

Comment: See: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/101395/should-i-make-my-resume-stand-out but mainly: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27758/would-adding-humor-to-my-cv-hurt-me

Comment: I wouldn't. It's a dated and (was) an overused joke even years ago. It may discredit the rest of your resume. "What else on here is a 'clever' joke?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving this question some benefit of the doubt...

> But say I'm applying for a high demand job, where there are many applications/job. Would just being noticed be worth the chance they don't like the non-professionalism?
>
> Could you explain why the trade-off wouldn't be worth it, maybe as an answer?

*Especially* for a high demand job with many applications, hiring managers are busy people. Putting something into your application that indicates you don't take the job completely seriously might be a way to get their attention, but not in a good way. There's a chance that they catch the "person of the year" line, assume it's a lie, and reject your application based on the lie. There's a chance they look up the person of the year to fact check you, figure out the joke, and still reject your application based on wasting their time or not taking the application process seriously.

The risk you run is that this stunt catches attention, but for the wrong reasons.

There are less risky ways to get noticed. If you don't have much work experience yet, listing some hobbies on a résumé can catch someone's eye. Or listing a GPA, if it's high. Or linking to a portfolio of projects you've done previously, or to a personal website. Even just having a well-formatted résumé can catch people's eye in a good way. I can't imagine a circumstance where a joke on a résumé would be wise.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you go more into the alternate scenario where you leave out the joke and don't stick out?

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside the broader question of whether jokes can be helpful in resumes, *this particular joke* is unlikely to help, because it's already been done to death.

[Here is an article from 2013](http://nymag.com/intelligencer/2013/09/twitter-bio-time-person-of-year-man-2006.html) explaining why the joke is tired. It notes that 1404 people on Twitter have this joke in their bios; when I ran the same search today, the number had risen to 3403.

If you want to impress a recruiter with your creativity and sense of humour, look for a fresher joke.